# SQL: How to compare tables, i.e. count rows in joined tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sas, dataset

I'm joining two tables and I'd like to get some simple statistics describing that operation, i.e.:

- how many rows I have **in total** in each of tables,
- how many of them will be **joined**
- how many will be left **unjoined**

I'm sure there must be some smart and simple method to get all the information on-the-fly - without creating and counting additional flags/variables and without long sequence of queries.

It would be also great to have such solution for joining more than two data sets - and count easily **7 groups of records** visible on the image below, when **3 tables** are compared.

I'm currently querying from SAS, but I often face the same problem working with Oracle and MS SQL - I'm looking for some dbms-agnostic solution.

[image]

Comment: please provide some sample data really helpful

Comment: You say dbms-agnostic, but tag MySQL.

Comment: @D-Shih - I just have thousands of records on both sides. The first one is reference - the whole active portfolio. The second one contains products with some parameters calculated. I suppose that full outer join will left some unjoined records on both sides (part of active portfolio without calculated parameters and also parameters calculated for products which are no longer in active portfolio). I'd like to know the shape of the relation.

Comment: @jarlh - do you know MySQL solution for the problem? It'd be great to know and I hope we'll be able to adjust it for another dbms or even make it dbms-agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working in SAS PROC SQL, one of the most useful options is `verbose` . For example:

```
%macro create_data(num, min, max);
  /* Creates sample datasets */
  DATA have&num.;
      do i=&min. to &max.;
          ID = i; OUTPUT;
      end; DROP i;
  RUN;
%mend create_data;

%create_data(1,1,10);
%create_data(2,5,15);
%create_data(3,9,100);

PROC SQL verbose;
    /* Sample join */
    CREATE table want as
        SELECT have1.ID as ID1, have2.ID as ID2, have3.ID as ID3
        FROM have1
        FULL JOIN have2
            on have1.ID=have2.ID
        RIGHT JOIN have3
            on have3.ID=have1.ID;
QUIT;
```

Would print the following in your SAS log:

```
Data Set WORK.HAVE1 is num=1 and tag=0001. NOBS=10, lrecl=8.
Data Set WORK.HAVE2 is num=2 and tag=0002. NOBS=11, lrecl=8.
Data Set WORK.HAVE3 is num=3 and tag=0004. NOBS=92, lrecl=8.
NOTE: Table WORK.WANT created, with 92 rows and 3 columns.
```

This is very useful for seeing the behavior of the joins especially with multiple datasets.

If you are working outside of SAS and looking for a generic SQL solution, I think your best (and fastest) solution would be to query the counts. For example, from the above selection:

```
* how many rows I have in total in each of tables ;
SELECT count(*) from have1;
SELECT count(*) from have2;
SELECT count(*) from have3;
* how many of them are joined ;
SELECT count(*) from want;
* how many will be left unjoined ;
SELECT count(*) from want where missing(ID1) or missing(ID2) or missing(ID3);
```

It is hard to give you additional advice without knowing specifics. Part of the reason SQL does not have a standard solution for this is that different type of joins are inherently much different from each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the distribution of keys across tables by doing:

```
select in1, in2, in3, count(*) as numkeys, min(key) as key1, max(key) as key2
from (select key, sum(in1) as in1, sum(in2) as in2, sum(in3) as in3
      from ( (select key, count(*) as in1, 0 as in2, 0 as in3 from table1 group by key
             ) union all
             (select key, 0 as in1, count(*) as in2, 0 as in3 from table2 group by key
             ) union all
             (select key, 0 as in1, 0 as in2, count(*) as in3 from table3 group by key
             ) 
            ) t123
      group by key
     ) k
group by in1, in2, in3;
```

The rows were all the values are non-zero are the ones returned by an inner join.  If the "key" is a primary key, then all the values will be 0 or 1 (other than the count).

Comment: Thank you. Nice and concise solution resulting in small table: \\\
in1 | in2 | in3 | numkeys \\\
 0  |   0  |   1  |  result \\\
 0  |   1  |   1  |  result \\\
 1  |   0  |   1  |  result \\\
 1  |   1  |   1   | result \\\
Not all the answers I was looking for, but it's simplicity is impressive, thanks a lot! [edit: crap, no linebreaks in comments allowed...]